# CBPeripheral interaction with Windows

Tags: ios, windows, bluetooth, bluetooth-lowenergy, core-bluetooth

I have an app in my iPhone device. The app is advertising CBPeripheral service. I already created one app on mac which allows it to interact with MAC desktop using CBCentral. It basically exchanges some data with MAC initiated handshake. I wanted to make interact the Windows 7 PC to interact with the iPhone app in the similar manner. I am unable to find any proper way to do it.

I have found [this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-in/library/windows/hardware/hh450802(v=vs.85).aspx), but it is minimum supported in Windows 8. Is there any way to do it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no support from Microsoft for Bluetooth 4.0 AKA BTLE prior to Windows 8.

Comment: Is there any third party framework or API available so that I can make it work on Windows. Also, I got stuck in similar problem for Android too. The peripheral advertisement is not supported untill the newest version of Android i.e. Lollipop. So I am unable to find out the way I can make advertisement possible in older version of android.

Comment: Not that I know of. But MS is not my thing.

Comment: Okay. Thanks for your help. Please post back if you know somebody/something that may work. I have posted one another question as I am unable to make it work even on Windows 8. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27287558/windows-8-0-not-discovering-cbperipheral