# Windows 8.0 not discovering CBPeripheral

Tags: windows, bluetooth, core-bluetooth, cbperipheral

I have a sample iPhone application taken from https://github.com/KhaosT/CBPeripheralManager-Demo/tree/master/PeripheralModeTest. I am advertising my peripheral service as follows.

```
- (void)peripheralManager:(CBPeripheralManager *)peripheral didAddService:(CBService *)service error:(NSError *)error
{
    NSLog(@"didAddService start");
    NSLog(@"Added");
    NSDictionary *advertisingData = @{CBAdvertisementDataLocalNameKey : @"BTService", CBAdvertisementDataServiceUUIDsKey : @[[CBUUID UUIDWithString:@"EBA38950-0D9B-4DBA-B0DF-BC7196DD44FC"]]};

    [peripheral startAdvertising:advertisingData];
    NSLog(@"didAddService end");
}
```

I have taken windows app code sample from https://code.msdn.microsoft.com/windowsapps/Bluetooth-Generic-5a99ef95. I replaced the Heart rate UUID with the service UUID. But on running it, it is unable to find the service mentioned.

```
void Scenario1_DeviceEvents::RunButton_Click(Object ^ /* sender */, RoutedEventArgs ^ /* e */)
{
    RunButton->IsEnabled = false;

    Vector<String^>^ additionalProperties = ref new Vector<String^>;
    additionalProperties->Append("System.Devices.ContainerId");

    Platform::Guid lol = Platform::Guid::Guid(0xEBA38950, 0x0D9B, 0x4DBA, 0xB0, 0xDF, 0xBC, 0x71, 0x96, 0xDD, 0x44, 0xFC);
    create_task(DeviceInformation::FindAllAsync(

        GattDeviceService::GetDeviceSelectorFromUuid(lol), additionalProperties))
        .then([this](Windows::Devices::Enumeration::DeviceInformationCollection^ devices)
    {
        this->devices = devices;

        if (devices->Size > 0)
        {
            Dispatcher->RunAsync(CoreDispatcherPriority::Normal, ref new DispatchedHandler([this, devices]()
            {
                DevicesListBox->Items->Clear();

                auto serviceNames = ref new Vector<String^>();

                for_each(begin(devices), end(devices), [=](DeviceInformation^ device) 
                {
                    serviceNames->Append(device->Name);
                });

                cvs->Source = serviceNames;
                DevicesListBox->Visibility = Windows::UI::Xaml::Visibility::Visible;
            }));
        }
        else
        {
            MainPage::Current->NotifyUser(L"Could not find any Heart Rate devices. Please make sure your " +
                "device is paired and powered on!",
                NotifyType::StatusMessage);
        }

        Dispatcher->RunAsync(CoreDispatcherPriority::Normal, ref new DispatchedHandler([this]() 
        {
            RunButton->IsEnabled = true;
        }));
    }).then([](task<void> finalTask)
    {
        try
        {
            // Capture any errors and exceptions that occured during device discovery
            finalTask.get();
        }
        catch (COMException^ e)
        {
            MainPage::Current->NotifyUser("Error: " + e->Message, NotifyType::ErrorMessage);
        }
    });
}
```

I tried pairing the device with windows. But still no luck. It has been so frustating, no proper support for discovering devices.

Comment: Have you tried to search for peripheral without filtering the services advertised? Do you have another device (iOS) to check with an app like LightBlue (or any equivalent on Android or WindowsPhone, or other OS) can find you iOS app?

Comment: No, I haven't tried without filtering the services. I have tried my iPhone app with a different app on MAC OSX which implements CBCentral and it works very fine with all the characteristics read and write. Have you worked with the similar usecase? I am trying to get it work, but I am unable to.

Comment: I was just trying to point out if your issue was only on your Windows app or not. Try without filtering the dervice furing the scan to ser if it can find it.

Comment: Hi, @larme I tried my iPhone app with LightBlue on another iPhone and I was able to discover my custom service. I was able to interact with it fine. I noticed one more behaviour, I emulated the heartrate service using LightBlue and tried to use the original windows app sample to see if it works. But, alas it didn't. Do you have any idea why this kind of behaviour might be happening?